# Django and Python logging what is the full dictionary for the formatter?

Tags: python, django, logging

Apologies if the title is vague. Feel free to edit to include the correct terminology.
In settings.py, I have the LOGGING dictionary with this formatter:

```
    'formatters': {
    'standard': { 
        'format': '{asctime} {message}',
        'style' : '{',
    }
```

I understand that asctime is the time that the log message was generated, and message is the message itself. But I don't know what other options are available.

1. Is the message itself a Python dictionary, and the curly-braced items are keys in the dict?
2. How can I view all keys in that dictionary? I assume {severity} is in there somewhere. What else can I enter?

Also, what are the various options under 'style'?

Comment: Severity is called `levelname` in that config. Many examples of options are given in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/logging/). All possibilities are documented in [logging docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes)

Comment: And yes, it is plain python dict. `style` is one of '$', '{' and '%' and indicates string interpolation method ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter))

Comment: Thanks a million. I figured there was an easy list somewhere, and that I was practicing bad Google-Fu.